# Is it good practice to have hyperlinks to acronyms in captions of a MSc thesis?

Tags: thesis, formatting, hyperlinks

I have inserted hyperlinks to acronyms list (by using the command `\gls{acronym:NASA}` in my LaTex project) in captions of figures and tables (see images below as example), in this way, if the reader click on the acronym then the list of acronyms appears (note that the hyperlinks are hilighted with a different color). I tought that is better to remove the hyperlink and leave simple the acronym because the list of figures seems to not have a good aspect. What is better to do?
[image: single enter]
[image: list of figures]
[image: figure with caption]
[image: list of acronyms]

Comment: This is really a LaTeX question: How do I make the acronym, including link, also appear in the table of figures without having it all spelled out.

Comment: Hi @WolfgangBangerth I simply want ot know if it is a good practice to show the hyperlink in the captions, nothing else.

Comment: If it helps your readers, it's good. Whether it is necessary to explain the acronym NASA may be debatable, but things such as ZVC make sense to explain.

Comment: Nitpick: I have always found LaTeX default hyperlink colors to be neither here nor there. Take a look at something like acronym for (subjectively) better UX with tooltips on hover instead of following the document back and forth: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161478. And keep in mind some readers would prefer to print it out, so it should still be usable in the paper form.